# Open neighbourhoods & polish spaces - typo in Marker's notes?

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, descriptive-set-theory

A very (very!) easy question that merges together the very basic concepts of two fields that I find always problematic for my understanding, namely topology and descriptive set theory. Everything starts from a passage taken from the – rightly praised – [notes](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512/dst.pdf)  written by David Marker on descriptive set theory.

> If $\sigma \in \mathbb{N}^{<\omega}$, let $N_{\sigma} := \{ f \in \mathcal{N} \ : \ \sigma \subset f  \}$. Then $N_\sigma$ is an open neighborhood of $f$.

In general I find that being able to spot a typo is a good measurement of the understanding of a certain field or topic. In those topics I am completely at loss, and I do not trust my logic, but indeed I think this is a typo (most probably one of those typos that a reasonable reader could spot and go on without much thoughts). Considering I do have doubts, here there is my line of reasoning...

The correct statement should be that $N_\sigma$ is an open neighbourhood of $\sigma$, because we endow $\mathcal{N}$ with the discrete topology and thus every $f \in \mathcal{N}$ is open. Given a topological space $(X, \tau)$, a neighbourhood $N_x$ of a point $x$ is deemed open when there is an open set $G \in \tau$ such that $x \in G \subset N_x$. Thus in our case, every $f$ is an open set that contains $\sigma$ and that is also a subset of $N_\sigma$, where the union of all those open sets given by the various $f$ is $N_\sigma$ itself.

**Questions**

- *Am I right? Is the logic sound?*
- *If this is not the case, why is $N_\sigma$ an open neighbourhood of $f$?*

As always, any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\sigma$ is not even an element of the space $\mathcal N$.  We do not endow $\mathcal N$ with the discrete topology.  Notation $\sigma \subset f$ means $\sigma$ is a restriction of $f$.  So this open set $N_\sigma$ consists of all infinite $f$ that extend the finite recipe $\sigma$.

For example, take this case: $\sigma := \{(0,17)\} \in \mathbb N^1$.  Then $N_\sigma$ is all $f \in \mathbb N^\omega$ such that $f(0)=17$.  This is an open set for the product topology of $\mathcal N = \mathbb N ^ \omega$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I do see now most of my mistakes. Due to the fact that I have the feeling I am getting finally something I feel it was always hidden to my eyes regarding topology, here there is my comment (divided in various numbered parts) with some statements and the general hidden question “Is my understanding finally correct?”. Any feedback regarding this flow of thoughts will be enormously appreciated!

Comment: **1.** It is $\mathbb{N}$ that we endow with the discrete topology, and then we get $\mathcal{N} := \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \equiv \mathbb{N}^\omega$. By looking at the natural topology of $\mathcal{N}$, i.e. the **product topology** on it, we get the open sets of $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: **2.** Thus, we have that each $\sigma$ is open in $\mathbb{N}^{<\omega}$, because taking into account the product topology of $\mathbb{N}^{<\omega}$, every element of the $n$-tuple is open in $\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the discrete topology. _Example:_ $\sigma = \{ (0, 17) \}$ is open in $\mathbb{N}^1$, because $0$ and $17$ are open in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: **3.** Hence, extending $\sigma$, we get the $f$ that are infinite and belong to $\mathcal{N}$. Thus, in order to find the open sets of $\mathcal{N}$, we apply the same line of reasoning of point (2) here, starting from the $\sigma$. Thus, an arbitrary $f \supset \sigma$ is open because $\sigma$ is open due to point (2), and we can continue with that line of reasoning a countable number of times.

Comment: **4.** $N_\sigma$ is an **open neighbourhood** of $f$ because it is made of all the other $f$ that share $\sigma$ and $f$ itself is open, being thus also a subset of $N_\sigma$.

Comment: **5.** We focus on $N_\sigma$ simply because this is a **basis** for the topology of $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: I hope it doesn't look like I am taking advantage of your kindness, but this a feedback regarding these thoughts would be truly enlightening. Thanks a lot!

Comment: **2.** is wrong.  $\sigma$ is an element of $\mathbb N^{<\omega}$, not a subset of it, so certainly $\sigma$ is not "open in $\mathbb N^{<\omega}$". **3.** is wrong, $f$ is not "open" since it is not a subset of $\mathcal N$.

Answer (score 1):

GEdgar's answer is being a little too kind: there clearly is a mistake in the notes. The correct statement is just that ${\cal N}_{\sigma}$ is open in $\cal N$. I think that the author may have meant to write something like  "${\cal N}_{\sigma}$ is an open neighbourhood of any if its elements $f$". In your (accurate) quotation the second $f$ is an unspecified free variable and that makes the statement obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I do see your point, because it is on  a meta level (so to speak). In some ways, my problem was more basic, because it was really about the nature of the neighbourhood itself (see the five comments I wrote below GEdgar's answer, that I am still not sure are right or not).